# Aquamacs+slime: Loading a lisp file at startup

Tags: emacs, slime, aquamacs

I'm running Aquamacs + Slime and I'm able to start Slime automatically when I start Aquamacs. However, when I try to load a lisp file after that I keep getting various errors depending on how I'm trying to load the file. Here's my preferences.el

```lisp
(setq inferior-lisp-program "~/ccl/dx86cl64"
  slime-startup-animation nil)
(require 'slime)
(split-window-horizontally)
(other-window 1)
(slime)
(eval-after-load "slime"
   '(progn 
       (slime-compile-and-load-file "/Users/xxxxx/xxxxx/load-seq.lisp")
 ))
```

I get the following error

```
error: Buffer *inferior-lisp* is not associated with a file.
```

I've tried other functions including `load` `compile-and-load` and `slime-load-file` and got  the following errors respectively...

```
Invalid read syntax: #
Symbol's function definition is void: compile-and-load
error: Not connected.
```

The lisp file loads (and compiles) fine when I do `(load "/Users/xxxxx/xxxxx/load-seq.lisp")` from the slime REPL. It seems like when I put it in Preferences.el, it does not wait for slime to load even though I'm using `eval-after-load`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You happened to misunderstand the use of the `slime-compile-and-load-file` function. Its docstring says:

> `(slime-compile-and-load-file &optional POLICY)`
>
> Compile and load **the buffer's file** and highlight compiler notes.

The function operates on a file which is already associated with the current buffer, and it expects a compiling policy, not a filename, as its (optional) argument. So your code should have been like this:

```lisp
(slime)
(add-hook 'slime-connected-hook
          (lambda ()
            (find-file "/Users/xxxxx/xxxxx/load-seq.lisp")
            (slime-compile-and-load-file)))
```

where `slime-connected-hook` contains a list of functions to be called when SLIME connects to a Lisp server.

But I'm not sure if the Emacs init file is a right place to load such a non-Emacs Lisp code. The CCL init file would be a better place to do it. Refer to [2.4. Personal Customization with the Init File](http://ccl.clozure.com/ccl-documentation.html#Personal-Customization-with-the-Init-File) in the CCL manual.

Additionally, the `load` function is for executing a Emacs Lisp code. `slime-load-file` is a right function to call, but it happened to be called too early (or before SLIME connects to a Lisp server). It would have worked if it had been added to the `slime-connected-hook` hook. Actually, I'd like to recommend `slime-load-file` over `slime-compile-and-load-file` if you don't have a valid excuse for compiling the Lisp code whenever you start Emacs (and again you really want to do it in Emacs):

```lisp
(add-hook 'slime-connected-hook
          (lambda ()
            (slime-load-file "/Users/xxxxx/xxxxx/load-seq.lisp")))
```

Finally, there is no function called `compile-and-load`.